# IsNumeric/IsError returns an error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm quite new to VBA and working on a custom function (which will be used for more complicated purposes in the future - that is the reason for which I want to do this using VBA instead of standard formulas) whose task should be to get the date from the cell and specify its position (i.a. row number) within the column (e.g. column A).

This simple task I have solved by the following procedure:

```
Function TempRowNumber(OrgDate)
    TempRowNumber = WorksheetFunction.Match(OrgDate, Range("A:A"), 0)
End Function
```

It works well, of course. However the problem is, that it may happen that the date entered into function is not included in the range. In this case, the function should search for the latest entered date, before that date.  As in this range the dates are always sorted chronologically, I planned to construct an error checking formula (as an condition) and the appropriate loop.

The problem is, that if I write a formula like this:

```
=ISERROR(MATCH(C23;A:A;0))
```

it's all good (the formula returns TRUE if the date from cell C23 is found within the column A, and FALSE if the date is not found). But if try to rewrite this formula into VBA procedure, i.a.:

```
Function FindDate(OrgDate)

FindDate = IsError(WorksheetFunction.Match(OrgDate, Range("A:A"), 0))

End Function
```

the custom function returns `#VALUE!` error if the date is not found (and FALSE if it's not). 
Below I attach a snapshot about what I describe.

[image]

Have you any idea what should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the *Iif()* and *IsError)* functions.

Comment: But I actually use the IsError() function and it does return "#VALUE!" instead of TRUE value if the date which I search for is not found. However, the Iif() function only specify what to do in case of TRUE and FALSE value, whereas I have a problem with the condition (as decribed above, VBA procedure wrote by me results in FALSE value or "#VALUE!" error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the reason behind it but this works:

```
Function FindDate(Orgdate)
    FindDate = IsError(Application.Match(Orgdate, Range("A:A"), 0))
End Function
```

Logically it should work the same way as `WorksheetFunction.Match` and can be evaluated by `IsError` the same way but I've tried it and I'm getting the same result as yours.

Comment: @azera Np. Thanks for accepting although technically I didn't answer your question. It is beyond me right now really. But lets see, we have a lot of MS MVP's here who might be able to shed light on your issue. I'm interested as well. As I've said, logically it should work.

Comment: Relevant page from Chip Pearson's site [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/callingworksheetfunctionsinvba.aspx). Using `WorksheetFunction.whatever` throws run-time errors so you need `On Error` statements to catch them rather than looking at the return value. `Application.whatever` doesn't throw run-time errors and the return value can be tested with `IsError`

Comment: @barrowc Ah cool stuff. As always Chip's the chief :). Although you need not actually pass the result to a variant type as seen above.